# 2147467259 7FFFBFFB(hex) Error

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, compilation

when I try to run DataBind() on my DataList to enhance ObjectDataSource wired to GetOfferPhotosAccPhotoTableAdapter in .xsd file I get the error: (translated)

> The type
>   webpresence.App_Code.OfferDetailsTableAdapters
>   .GetOfferPhotosAccPhotoTableAdapter
>   has multiple meanings it can originate
>   from assembly C:\Users\Admin
>   User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8c09cffe\c354bcf3\App_Code.hdvmwn8q.DLL
>   or from
>   F:\C_Sharp\C_Sharp_Projs\webpresence\webpresence\bin\webpresence.DLL
>   Set the assembly in type name explicitly.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please explain the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try do a "Clean Solution", rebuild, and run again.

If that fails, restart Visual Studio

and if that fails, manually clean out that temp directory...

basically you've got an uncleaned reference dll that's causing the compiler to go nuts because it's seeing your class/methods in 2 places and doesn't know which one to use, though I've no idea what the relevance of your Subject is.

Comment: Hi, Cerebrus, the title is the error number generated by the compiler dec AND hex formatted
Hi, Eoin, I#ve tried both. Got the same error. It's a web project. There's OfferDetails.xsd created. On the page I have SupplObjectDataSource, that uses TableAdapter from xsd file and SupplDataList connected to this DataSoursce. To prove some values beforehand I run SupllDataList.DataBind() after changing input parameter. And error occurs here

Comment: Hi, again, I got it. While choosing DataAdapter from the dropdownlist while configuring ObjectDataSource one get the choice between "generic" name and long path to the DataAdapter, you should take the short "generic" one